# How to fix this bug in a math expression evaluator

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, eval, rpn

I've written a typical evaluator for simple math expressions (arithmetic with some custom functions) in F#. While it seems to be working correctly, some expressions don't evaluate as expected, for example, these work fine:

- eval "5+2" --> 7
- eval "sqrt(25)^2" --> 25
- eval "1/(sqrt(4))" --> 0.5
- eval "1/(2^2+2)" --> 1/6 ~ 0.1666...

but these don't:

- eval "1/(sqrt(4)+2)" --> evaluates to 1/sqrt(6) ~ 0.408...
- eval "1/(sqrt 4 + 2)" --> will also evaluate to 1/sqrt(6)
- eval "1/(-1+3)" --> evaluates to 1/(-4) ~ -0.25

the code works as follows, tokenization (string as input) -> to rev-polish-notation (RPN) -> evalRpn

I thought that the problem seems to occur somewhere with the unary functions (functions accepting one operator), these are the sqrt function and the negation (-) function. I don't really see what's going wrong in my code. Can someone maybe point out what I am missing here?

this is my implementation in F#

```
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

type Token = 
    | Num of float
    | Plus
    | Minus
    | Star
    | Hat
    | Sqrt
    | Slash
    | Negative
    | RParen
    | LParen

let hasAny (list: Stack<'T>) = 
    list.Count <> 0

let tokenize (input:string) = 
    let tokens = new Stack<Token>()
    let push tok = tokens.Push tok
    let regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]+(\.+\d*)?|\+|\-|\*|\/|\^|\)|\(|pi|e|sqrt")
    for x in regex.Matches(input.ToLower()) do
        match x.Value with
        | "+" -> push Plus
        | "*" -> push Star
        | "/" -> push Slash
        | ")" -> push LParen
        | "(" -> push RParen
        | "^" -> push Hat
        | "sqrt" -> push Sqrt
        | "pi" -> push (Num System.Math.PI)
        | "e" -> push (Num System.Math.E)
        | "-" ->
            if tokens |> hasAny then
                match tokens.Peek() with
                | LParen -> push Minus
                | Num v -> push Minus
                | _ -> push Negative
            else 
                push Negative

        | value -> push (Num (float value))
    tokens.ToArray() |> Array.rev |> Array.toList



let isUnary = function
    | Negative | Sqrt -> true
    | _ -> false


let prec = function
    | Hat -> 3
    | Star | Slash -> 2
    | Plus | Minus -> 1
    | _ -> 0



let toRPN src =
    let output = new ResizeArray<Token>()
    let stack = new Stack<Token>()
    let rec loop = function
        | Num v::tokens -> 
            output.Add(Num v)
            loop tokens
        | RParen::tokens ->
            stack.Push RParen
            loop tokens
        | LParen::tokens ->
            while stack.Peek() <> RParen do
                output.Add(stack.Pop())
            stack.Pop() |> ignore // pop the "("
            loop tokens
        | op::tokens when op |> isUnary ->
            stack.Push op
            loop tokens
        | op::tokens ->
            if stack |> hasAny then
                if prec(stack.Peek()) >= prec op then
                    output.Add(stack.Pop())
            stack.Push op
            loop tokens
        | [] -> 
            output.AddRange(stack.ToArray())
            output 
    (loop src).ToArray()

let (@) op tok = 
    match tok with
    | Num v -> 
        match op with
        | Sqrt -> Num (sqrt v)
        | Negative -> Num (v * -1.0)
        | _ -> failwith "input error"
    | _ -> failwith "input error"

let (@@) op toks = 
    match toks with
    | Num v,Num u -> 
        match op with
        | Plus -> Num(v + u)
        | Minus -> Num(v - u)
        | Star -> Num(v * u)
        | Slash -> Num(u / v)
        | Hat -> Num(u ** v)
        | _ -> failwith "input error"
    | _ -> failwith "inpur error"


let evalRPN src = 
    let stack = new Stack<Token>()
    let rec loop = function
        | Num v::tokens -> 
            stack.Push(Num v)
            loop tokens
        | op::tokens when op |> isUnary ->
            let result = op @ stack.Pop()
            stack.Push result
            loop tokens
        | op::tokens ->
            let result = op @@ (stack.Pop(),stack.Pop())
            stack.Push result
            loop tokens
        | [] -> stack
    if loop src |> hasAny then
        match stack.Pop() with 
        | Num v -> v 
        | _ -> failwith "input error"
    else failwith "input error"  

let eval input = 
    input |> (tokenize >> toRPN >> Array.toList >> evalRPN)
```

Comment: You should trim this code down.  We don't really need to see all of that, just the stuff having to do with `sqrt` and `-`.

Comment: @mydogisbox I am not certain whether the problem is specific to the functions sqrt and (-), I posted the code so that people could see the whole picture, it's pretty concise so there's no trouble with readability.

Comment: @ZaidAjaj - the idea is to come up with a minimal example.  If all you need to show the bug is `/` unary `-` and `+` then remove all the rest of the code to get better help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before answering your specific question, did you notice you have another bug? Try `eval "2-4"` you get `2.0` instead of `-2.0`.

That's probably because along these lines:

```
match op with
    | Plus -> Num(v + u)
    | Minus -> Num(v - u)
    | Star -> Num(v * u)
    | Slash -> Num(u / v)
    | Hat -> Num(u ** v)
```

`u` and `v` are swapped, in commutative operations you don't notice the difference, so just revert them to `u -v`.

Now regarding the bug you mentioned, the cause seems obvious to me, by looking at your code you missed the precedence of those unary operations:

```
let prec = function
    | Hat -> 3
    | Star | Slash -> 2
    | Plus | Minus -> 1
    | _ -> 0
```

I tried adding them this way:

```
let prec = function
    | Negative -> 5
    | Sqrt -> 4
    | Hat -> 3
    | Star | Slash -> 2
    | Plus | Minus -> 1
    | _ -> 0
```

And now it seems to be fine.

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't check a lot of examples, thanks for going the through the code. I 'translated' this from pseudo-code to F# with some changes to make it as minimal as possible, the peudo-code however didn't bother to add precedence for unary operators, neither it did something to them while converting to RPN.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: meh, seems I was late, Gustavo posted the answer while I was wondering about the parentheses. Oh well.*

- Unary operators have the wrong precedence. Add the primary case `| a when isUnary a -> 4` to `prec`.
- The names of `LParen` and `RParen` are consistently swapped throughout the code. `(` maps to `RParen` and `)` to `LParen`!

It runs all tests from the question properly for me, given the appropriate precedence, but I haven't checked the code for correctness.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, RParen means OpenParen and LParen means CloseParen, the rest of the code is consistent with their use! I didn't notice that, for me it is something natural to write it in this way because I ususally read from right to left so that the opening paren is actually the left one if read from left to right and it is right paren if read from right to left. Thanks for your answer.